# linux shell script to zip all files

Tags: linux, shell, command

This is example path of my application

```
/var/www/html/folder1/folder2/folder3/
```

I need to fetch all 90 days older files of "folder3" and save them as a zip file named "folder2" using a shell script. I tried writing some piece of code in shell script:-

```
filaname = awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}' <<< "/var/www/html/folder1/folder2/folder3/"

#above command retuns folder2

zip filaname find /var/www/html/folder1/folder2/folder3/* -ctime -90
```

i was trying to send output of **find** command to **zip** command but it did not work.

Can someone please suggest how can i achieve this.

Comment: shell? what language? are you even remotely familiar with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or try this:

```
find /var/www/html/folder1/folder2/folder3/ -type f -mtime +90 -exec zip filename.zip {} \;
```

Comment: it's a way to pass a list of files generated by the `find` command

Answer (score 1):

```
$ zip files.zip `find /var/www/html/folder1/folder2/folder3/ -type f -mtime +90`
```

Comment: I ran this command in script but got error "zip error: Nothing to do! (files.zip)"

Comment: possibly there is no matching files?

Comment: No, that folder contain one file